# How to call an asp control using getElementById() in a javascript function that is included in ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript

Tags: javascript, c#

I'm required to use ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript to run a javascript function while using asp.net's update panel.

My goal is to run my javascript function named Top10 with json parameter called jsonTable, in this function everything is working well aside from `var hfield = document.getElementById("<%=hf.ClientID%>");` which is supposedly get the asp.net's hiddenfield control but it keeps returning null. 
I reduced the code so that I can get to the point.

c#:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (!IsPostBack) {
        dtCurrentTop1O = dsCurrentTop10Winners.Tables["Top 10 Winners"];
        string strCurrentTop1O = serializer(dtCurrentTop1O);
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.updatePanel1, GetType(), "Javascript",
            "javascript:Top10(" + strCurrentTop1O + ");", true);
    }
}
```

Markup:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="head">
  <title></title>
  <script src="Scripts/Top10.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</asp:Content>
<asp: Content ID="Content2" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1">
  <asp: ScriptManager ID="scriptManager1" runat="server"></asp: ScriptManager>
  <asp: UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
      <asp: Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
        <asp: HiddenField ID="hf" runat="server" />
      </asp: Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

javascript: Top10.js

```
function Top10(jsonTable) {
    var chartImg;
    var hfield = document.getElementById("<%=hf.ClientID%>");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, the function you're calling is located in the file 'Top10.js'. AFAIK, ASP.NET won't resolve definitions like "<%=hf.ClientID%>" outside of ASP.NET specific files - .js files are delivered to the webclient 'as is' (static content) and not rendered server-side like .aspx files. You'll be able to confirm this when looking at the delivered source in your browsers dev-tools.

You could either place the javascript code directly inside your markup so that the ClientId will be resolved, add an additional hiddenFieldId-parameter to the TopFiveOutsagesCurrentLC function or directly set the HiddenFields content in your Page_Load method.

Example for direct js code in Markup:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="head">
 <title></title>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function TopFiveOutagesCurrentLC(jsonTable) {
   var chartImg;
   var hfield = document.getElementById("<%=hf.ClientID%>");
  };
 </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp: Content ID="Content2" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1">
 <asp: ScriptManager ID="scriptManager1" runat="server"></asp: ScriptManager>
 <asp: UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel1" runat="server">
   <ContentTemplate>
     <asp: Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
      <asp: HiddenField ID="hf" runat="server" />
     </asp: Panel>
   </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: I'm sorry for responding late. I already know this kind of approach and I'd say it works but what I'm trying to do is to put my javascript code in .js so that I can make my markup free from any javascript function.

Answer (score 0):

I've answered my question by finding the hiddenfield control and then added it to parameters for the javascript function.

```
      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
          {
          if (!IsPostBack) {
             HiddenField hf = (HiddenField)this.updatePanel1.FindControl("hf");
             dtCurrentTop1O = dsCurrentTop10Winners.Tables["Top 10 Winners"];
             string strCurrentTop1O = serializer(dtCurrentTop1O);
             ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.updatePanel1, GetType(), 
             "Javascript",
             "javascript:Top10(" + strCurrentTop1O + ","+hf.ClientID+");", true);
              }
           }
```